# How to \tag a line in a multiline equation under aligned environment?

Tags: math-mode, align, environments, tags

This does not work:

```
$\begin{aligned}
x^2 - y^2 & = x^2 + xy - xy - y^2             \\
          & = x(x + y) - y(x + y) \tag{hello} \\
          & = (x + y)(x - y)
\end{aligned}$
```

And the error says: `\tag not allowed here`
But this does:

```
\begin{align*}
x^2 - y^2 & = x^2 + xy - xy - y^2             \\
          & = x(x + y) - y(x + y) \tag{hello} \\
          & = (x + y)(x - y)
\end{align*}
```

And gives:
[image: difference of squares]

Which is almost what I want, but I don't want the equations to be center aligned (I want them to be left aligned, hence using `aligned` environment). How to fix that? Is there a way for the code in the first snippet to be corrected? Thanks!

Edit: I actually need to type this:

```
$\therefore$ $\begin{aligned}[t]
\text{angular speed} = \frac{2\pi}{T} & \implies \omega = \frac{2\pi}{T} \\
& \implies \omega = 2\pi \times \frac{1}{T} \\
& \implies \omega = 2 \pi \nu 
\end{aligned}$
```

[image]

And want to tag the last line with `$\nu = \frac{1}{T}$`. If there is some other way in which it looks good, I accept. Is there a way to add this?

Comment: Wrap aligned un the normal equation env (instead of your `$... $`) and place tag outside aligned. Aligned is an "inner" construction and can thus not produce eq numbers/tags

Comment: @daleif But the equation gets center aligned. I want it to be left aligned as in `aligned`.

Comment: Then use flalign instead of align and read up on how that env works and how many & you'll need. IMO displayed formulas should be centered.

Comment: @daleif It's still center aligned ... I am editing the question.

Comment: As I said look up how flalign works and how many & are needed per line, by ending lines with enough & contents are pushed left

Comment: Worked like charm, thanks @daleif! (You can add an answer)